# Opening a pdf file from asset folder

Tags: android

I can get the file from my asset folder like this

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/help_doc.pdf"), "application/pdf");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        try{
            startActivity(i);
        }catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Application Available to View PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

but when I select the application to open it, it either does not open or gives me an error saying `error opening file. it does not exist or cannot be read` but if i put it on my sdcard and click on it to open it I dont get this error so whats wrong with how I am doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`file://android_asset` only works in your app. What you are telling these others apps to do is to read `help_doc.pdf` out of *their* assets, and they do not have such a file.

You will need to either:

- Copy the file to external storage, or
- Copy the file to internal storage and use a `ContentProvider` to make it available to the PDF viewing app

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/Files) demonstrates the latter approach.

Comment: makes sense when you say it that way :)